# How to integrate your application with K-9 Mail android

Tags: android, email, email-client, k-9mail

I am working in project that needs to integrate client email , after long research I find library called k-9 do this function

I try integrate it to my app , I cant find any documentation just this article

https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/wiki/ThirdPartyApplicationIntegration

the function I need in my app , login + read incoming email

I can read incoming email throw broadcast

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final Uri k9Uri = Uri.parse("content://com.fsck.k9.messageprovider/inbox_messages/");

static String[] messages_projection = new String[] {
       "_id",
       "date",
       "sender",
       "subject",
       "preview",
       "account",
       "uri",
       "delUri"
     };

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Cursor curSt = mContext.getContentResolver().query(k9Uri, messages_projection, null, null, null);
    curSt.moveToFirst();
    String preview = curSt.getString(curSt.getColumnIndex("preview"));

}
```

but how can I intergrade login with specific configuration

could any one help me how to approach login , or someone advice me with another library to use

Comment: As per the link you provided, `Application developers willing to integrate their application with K-9`. This means that your users are forced to install K-9 mail. Don't take me bad, but it really doesn't seem a smart approach, to me.

Comment: me too can I find any other library do the same function

Comment: Depending on your needs, you can use the standard mail intent or use the JavaMail API.

Comment: "I find library called k-9 do this function" -- this is not a library. It is an app.

Comment: so you all recommended use standard mail or JavaMail API  , I was thinking in use JavaMail API , but I need something much easier to implement

Comment: K-9 Mail is an open-source email client for Android , so we can use it by overriding method do the same functions

Comment: I use the standard mail intent. Which means using the mail client the user already has on their phone without asking for their mail and password (which is what stops me from using the JavaMail API). Very easy to use. But it can't run in `silent mode`, while the JavaMail API can.